# Classification problem in pytorch with loss function CrossEntropyLoss returns negative output in prediction

Tags: cnn, pytorch

I am trying to train and predict SVHN dataset (VGG architecture). I get very high validate/test accuracy by just getting the largest output class. However, the output weights are of large positive and negative numbers. Are they supposed to parsed as exp(output)/sum(exp(output)) to be converted to probability? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The numbers to which you are referring are probably the [logits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455101/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-logits-in-tensorflow) of the NN. The logits have to be transformed using a activation function which could be:

- **[Softmax](https://medium.com/data-science-bootcamp/understand-the-softmax-function-in-minutes-f3a59641e86d) ( which you showed )** for classification tasks.
- **Linear activation function** for regression tasks.

**Softmax activation function :**

The mathematical notion is as follows:

$\Large S( y_i ) = \frac{ e^{y_i}}{ \sum e^{y_i} }$

It converts the logits to class probabilities that sum to 1. It is widely used in multiclass classification problems.

**CNNs for classification need to produce class probabilities which are produced by a softmax activation function at the output layer.**